# Bank Statement for spain schengen visa

Tags: schengen, proof-provenance-of-funds

is 2000 USD is enough for bank statement for someone who used to travel frequently to europe ? for one week tourism

Comment: What is your country of origin?

Comment: Yes however it's more about the activity than the amount.

Answer (score 4):

The bank statements serve several purposes.

- They want to see if you can pay for the trip.
- They want to see if you fit the profile of a genunie tourist or business traveller, i.e. if you appear at risk for overstaying and illegal immigration.

For the first point, $2,000 (approx €270/day) will be enough to cover cost of living for a week in Spain. Spain requires visitors to have a [*minimum* of EUR 598 for a one week visit](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/docs/handbook-annex_25_en.pdf). For longer visits the required minimum is EUR 62 per day. We don't know what the travel expenses will be, but it is likely enough as well. **But that is only half of the answer.**

For the second point, they want to see a *regular pattern of income and expenditures*, with income exceeding expenditures. This is more important than the balance at the end of the month. Here is a [great answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) to a similar question regarding the UK, but the same principle applies to Schengen visa.

Comment: @GayotFow, the OP asked if $2,000 in a bank account are enough for a week. I answered that it is not just the amount that matters. I'll clarify a bit more.

Comment: +1 very grateful for the official link to the subsistence tables!

Comment: @GayotFow, the edit history seems buggy, I didn't add the link myself.

Comment: It's a great link because it is rooted in national legislation and will serve the OP well because the info is absolutely authoritative. Great answer. Fully deserving lots of votes :)